# Switching a string in a token register to lowercase and processing via the package soul

Tags: capitalization, soul, letterspacing

I would like to store a string in a token register, transform it to all-lowercase, and process the resulting string via the macro `\caps` provided by the package `soul`. That is to say, transform the string characters to small capitals and typeset the latter with the ensuing letterspacing.

My problem involves the original string transformation to all-lowercase. I have tried with the TeX primitive \lowercase, with the LaTeX command \MakeLowercase, and with the corresponding command provided by the package `textcase`. With each alternative, I end up getting a different error message.

Next follows an MWE with one of my tentatives.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{soul}%,textcase}

\newtoks{\toktitle}
\newcommand{\doctitle}[1]{\toktitle={#1}}
% Workaround to have \caps doing its thing on a macro properly, 
% as described in the corresponding documentation.  
\def\soultitle{\MakeLowercase{\the\toktitle}}
\newcommand{\thetitle}{\caps\soultitle}
% One of my alternatives  
%\def\soultitle{\the\toktitle}
%\newcommand{\thetitle}{\caps\MakeLowercase{\soultitle}}    

\doctitle{This is the title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thetitle
\end{document}
```

Anyone could possibly provide guidance on this issue? Thanks so much in advance, as usual.

ANSWER: I just need to use the command `\soulregister` as depicted in the documentation of the package `soul`. The MWE above would then read as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{soul}

\soulregister{\MakeLowercase}{1}

\newtoks{\toktitle}
\newcommand{\doctitle}[1]{\toktitle={#1}}
% Workaround to have \caps doing its thing on a macro properly, 
% as described in the corresponding documentation.  
\def\soultitle{\the\toktitle}
\newcommand{\thetitle}{\caps{\MakeLowercase{\soultitle}}}

\doctitle{This is the title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thetitle
\end{document}
```

My apologies. Hope this is useful to somebody nonetheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a few `\expandafter` to adjust the order of expansion.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{soul}%,textcase}

\newtoks{\toktitle}
\newcommand{\doctitle}[1]{\toktitle={#1}}
% Workaround to have \caps doing its thing on a macro properly, 
% as described in the corresponding documentation.  

\newcommand{\thetitle}{\expandafter\lowercase\expandafter
                       {\expandafter\caps\expandafter{\the\toktitle}}}


\doctitle{This is the title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thetitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David, you are right. My issue can be solved as you say, but there is also the possibility of using the command `\soulregister` as I said in my edited post above. Of course, your solution goes straight to the core of the issue. Thank you very much for your attention.